# Deleting /usr/portage folder Gentoo

Tags: linux, root, gentoo

I have a Gentoo based Linux OS on my computer. But the portage tree is too old, so while installing some apps there are errors.

I downloaded an new portage snapshot for replacing my old one. But I can’t remove my /usr/portage folder because all files included there are read-only.

As root, I run `rm -rf /usr/portage` to delete it.

How can I remove portage folder to put my new portage snapshot there?

Comment: Have you tried 'sudo rm -rf /usr/portage' ?

Comment: I do everything as a root of the sustem. I tryed it, there is no effect

Comment: You could try to remount it read-write: `mount -o remount,rw /<mount_point_of_gentoo>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal procedure to update portage tree is to do

```
emerge --sync
```

You should also check [Gentoo handbook](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=2&chap=1).

Why can't you update this way?

Comment: There are some errors appearing during --sync process, i had tried it at first

Comment: What errors ? Maybe add them to the question ? Anyhow if you are really decided you can use the comment about 'remount'